# Junit REST tests?

Tags: testing, rest, junit

I am using Struts2, Spring 2 and Junit 4.5.

My main question is, whether even to test REST calls? Because, basically this are only calls to business logic and they don't have any logic theirs methods.

I have tests for all DAO and BL classes, rest xml and json handler, so I don't know what should I even test in REST calls - result codes/response/...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit tests for the REST calls may not give you value, but system tests exercising the entire system through REST will.

Comment: Yes, but I am using stress tests for this (JMeter).